# What's the way to go when inserting values to multiple tables?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, cakephp, auditing

I'm inserting some values onto `employees` table using this in the controller:

```
            $this->Employee->create();
            if ($this->CoreProgram->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Program has been added.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add record.');
            }
```

However, I want to insert a record to another table `audit`. More specifically, the current date along with `employee_id` field that I used for `employees`. What is the best approach to do this? Should I just create `$this->Audit->create();`? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Use an insert trigger on **employees** table that inserts audit entry into the **audit** table:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_employees_ins ON dbo.employees FOR INSERT AS  
BEGIN  

    INSERT dbo.audit( [op] ... employee_id ...)
    SELECT 'INS' ... employee_id
    FROM Inserted

END
```